# How to get the date difference by joining two tables?

Tags: sql-server, linq, date

I have table of data like,

```
Table1:

id  Name   date
--------------
1   xxx  01/01/2015
2   yyy  01/02/2015
3   aaa  02/03/2015

Table 2:

id Name   date
--------------
 1  xxx    07/01/1015
 2  xxx    09/01/2015
 3  yyy    05/02/2015
 4. aaa    04/03/2015
```

I am trying to get the date difference by joining two tables.But I have to get the difference by using Table1 when the name is occurred first time. If the duplicate value for the name is occurred means, it gets the difference by using Table2 alone. Please note the date in **(dd/mm/yyyy)** format
Result should look like this,

```
 Name  DateDifference

 xxx    6  (07/01/2015 - 01/01/2015)
 xxx    2  (07/01/2015 - 09/01/2015)
 yyy    4  (01/02/2015- 05/02/2015)
 aaa    2   (02/03/2015 -04/03/2015)
```

The SQL query I have tried is,

```
SELECT    s.spidername,   
        T1.Date, 
        MIN(T2.Date) AS Date2, 
        DATEDIFF("D", T1.Date, MIN(T2.Date)) AS DaysDiff

FROM    Spider_DailyJobCount T1
        LEFT JOIN Spider_DailyJobCount T2
            ON T1.SpiderName = T2.SpiderName
            AND T2.Date > T1.Date
join spider s on s.spidername = t1.spidername
 where //Condition
GROUP BY   T1.Date,s.spidername
```

LINQ query I have tried is,

```
var query = (from item1 in Table1
                join item2 in Table1 on item1.Name equals item2.SpiderName
                where item2.Date > item1.Date
                join origin in Table2 on item1.Name equals origin.Name
                where // condition
                group new { item1,item2 } by new {  item1.Name,item1.Date } into grp
                select new
                {                   

                    DayDiff = DbFunctions.DiffDays(grp.Key.Date, grp.Min(d => d.item2.Date)),
                }
                ).ToList();
```

I have tried these things, But could not get the needed output. I have tried only Table2 values. I really don't know how to get the value from Table1 for first occurrence. 
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

t-sql solution

```
declare @Table1 table
(
    id  int,
    Name    varchar(3),
    date    date
)

declare @Table2 table
(
    id  int,
    Name    varchar(3),
    date    date
)

set dateformat dmy

insert into @Table1 select 1,   'xxx',  '01/01/2015'
insert into @Table1 select 2,   'yyy',  '01/02/2015'
insert into @Table1 select 3,   'aaa',  '02/03/2015'

insert into @Table2 select 1,  'xxx',    '07/01/2015'
insert into @Table2 select 2,  'xxx',    '09/01/2015'
insert into @Table2 select 3,  'yyy',    '05/02/2015'
insert into @Table2 select 4,  'aaa',    '04/03/2015'

-- Actual Query
; with cte as
(
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Name order by date)
    from
    (
        select * from @Table1 union all select * from @Table2
    ) t
)
select  c1.Name, c1.date, c2.date, diff = datediff(day, c1.date, c2.date)
from    cte c1
    inner join cte c2   on  c1.Name = c2.Name
                and c1.rn   = c2.rn - 1
```

brief explaination :

- looks like your requrement is actually to find the date diff between 2 records
- So that is what the UNION ALL do. It combine both table into one
- row_number() is to assign a sequencial number to the rows with same name in date ascending order
- next is to get the date diff by INNER JOIN

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with LINQ syntax

Comment: How to do this SQl query without insert. ?

Comment: you don't need the insert. that is sample data for demonstrating the query. Use the part "Actual Query"

Comment: I got error like 'All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists'.

Comment: are you using my example or the acctual query ? Please post your query

Comment: Actually i am having Table1 date as "Created Date" and  Table2 date as "Date"

Comment: specify the actual column name instead of * and the column must match from both of the tables

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106325/discussion-between-sara-and-squirrel).